# Cache MongoDb connection with Next.js 10 TypeScript Project - API Route

Tags: mongodb, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to convert next.js/examples/with-mongodb/util/mongodb.js to TS so I can cache and resue my connections to Mongo within a TS next.js project. I'm getting a TS error on `cache.promise` that says:
`Type 'Promise<MongoClient | { client: MongoClient; db: Db; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<MongoClient>'`

How should I properly declare the mongo property on global to appease the TS gods?

```js
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";

const { DATABASE_URL, DATABASE_NAME } = process.env;

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongo: {
        conn: MongoClient | null;
        promise: Promise<MongoClient> | null;
      };
    }
  }
}

let cached = global.mongo;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function connect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(DATABASE_URL, opts).then((client) => {
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db(DATABASE_NAME),
      };
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}

export { connect };
```

Comment: nextjs with-mongodb has changed. Haven't you converted the new version to TypeScript. If yes, could you please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cache your connection, check latest nextjs with mongodb [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb). The official mongodb forum [experts have navigated](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/connections-not-closed-with-nextjs/115037/2?u=il_chi) me to this example project.

Try to use native solutions

Comment: this answer is outdated. you need to keep connection be cached in case of hot reloads... see the comments at  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.ts

Answer (score 1):

The '`conn`' property you are storing contains both `MongoClient` *and* `Db`.

In your global declaration for `mongo`, you have only included `MongoClient`. I have the exact same code in my project and the way I handle this is to simply create a basic type called `MongoConnection` which contains both. Code below.

```js
type MongoConnection = {
  client: MongoClient;
  db: Db;
};

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongo: {
        conn: MongoConnection | null;
        promise: Promise<MongoConnection> | null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the answer is to just make the mongo property an `any` like this:

```js
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongo: any;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Has someone found a better solution for this? If yes, please post as an answer.